# Is it possible to alphabetize a string in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm connecting Tableau to a data source that I have no control over, so I can't sort strings from the source. I have a field that can be up to 5 letters, but the order doesn't matter. For example, I would like to consider

```
'OLV' = 'VLO' = 'LOV'
```

etc. Is it possible to create a calculated field to alphabetize this string?

Comment: Not sure if you can reorder the string, but if all you care about is if the strings are "equal" you could do something like:
 
`CONTAINS([Primary Key], 'O') AND
CONTAINS([Primary Key], 'L') AND
CONTAINS([Primary Key], 'V')`

Then use that as a filter. Tools like Tableau Prep or Alteryx are better equipped to handle alphabetizing the string.

Comment: Thanks, since the string can be made up of any letter of alphabet I've created 26 calculated field with the above logic (`CONTAINS([Primary Key], 'A'`) and used those to determine equality. It's dirty, but works!

Comment: Another way would be to use sets. Without knowing your data, it's hard to say what's best. You may be able to adjust your SQL to bring in the data with a delimiter like O|L|V, then use Transform->Custom split to give you separate columns per letter (ie O, L, V). From there, I'm not sure what sorting you could do.. but it gives you an option to play with. https://community.tableau.com/thread/201960